# ASP/ASPX Label Visibility with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress

I am currently attempting to change the visibility of a label when a button is clicked. The label is initially hidden and will appear after the button is clicked.

I have tried using DevEx controls and the SetVisible() function. The function works, but if the label is rendered 'display: none' via css first like I want in my situation, it does nothing.

I have also attempted to use ASP labels and change the display property on click, but once again nothing seems to happen.

Style

```
.dxd
{
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fncShow(s, e) {
        //show devex label
        lblTest.SetVisible(true);
        //show ASP label
        document.getElementById("lblASP").style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

Body

```
<dx:ASPxButton runat="server" ID="btnTest" Text="Show" Width="100px" AutoPostBack="false">
    <ClientSideEvents Click="fncShow" />
</dx:ASPxButton>
<dx:ASPxLabel runat="server" ID="lblTest" Text="Test label" ClientInstanceName="lblTest" CssClass="dxd"></dx:ASPxLabel>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblASP" Text="Test label 2" CssClass="dxd"></asp:Label>
```

I've exhausted quite a few methods trying to get either controls to work with no success. At this point, I am interested to know if it is possible to have a label invisible first, and if it is possible how it is achievable using both controls. I am new to JS so maybe I am missing something, but all examples have been fruitless. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _display != visibility_. Trying setting `visibility: hidden;` in your CSS instead of `display: none;`.

Comment: Already tried that, doesn't work. Also worth noting, the DevEx label will stay invisible and the display property is changed.

Comment: Where is `lblTest` defined in the `fncShow` function? And are you sure that the label ID is still `lblASP` when it is rendered?

Comment: lblTest does not need to be defined, it has a ClientInstanceName property that can be referenced instead of retrieving it by Id, DevEx designed it this way. Once again, I have the SetVisible() working, i had two buttons that show/hide and it does it properly until you set the initial CSS to hide it. As for the ASP label's ID, I am not sure if it is changing, is there a reason it would?

Comment: I am now reading  that the names can be changed at run time, this seems to be my issue, is there a way to either know the name it will be changed to, or prevent it from changing?

Comment: If you are referring to the ID, there is, IIRC, an ASP attribute like `ClientID` or something, that would prevent the ID from being munged.(Been a few years since I've done any .NET development.) Looks like there is also a `ClientIDMode` attribute which you can set to `static`.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was missing a few small settings to make all this come together.

On the DevEx control there is a property called `ClientVisible`, set that to `false` for the object to be initially hidden. After that, you can freely use `label.SetVisible()` to show and hide it.

On the ASP label, Kevin was right about the `ClientIDMode` needing to be set to `static`. Once set to `static` the ID wont change up, and both `display` and `visibility` properties can be changed using the `document.getElementByID().style.visiblity` or `style.display`, whichever you prefer.